# Google maps geocoding does not return location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to use Google Maps Geocoding API in javascript. I have the following code:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocodeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode({"address": address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(results[0].geometry))
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Result that I got for a correct address is:

```
{"location":{},"location_type":"ROOFTOP","viewport":{"O":{"O":52.2080810197085,"j":52.2107789802915},"j":{"j":21.018444019708568,"O":21.02114198029153}}}
```

As you can see it doesn't have location properly set. Any suggestion what is wrong here?

Comment: What are you going to use the coordinates for? You can get them from the  google.maps.LatLng object using the documented `.lat()` and `.lng()` methods.

Answer (score 4):

`Location` property is of `google.maps.LatLng` object type, which in turn requires explicit conversion to print lat/lng values,e.g:

```
var sval = results[0].geometry.location.toString();
```

Or you could access lat/lng values using corresponding functions:

```
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

In order to print string representation of `Location` property you could replace:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(results[0].geometry));
```

with

```
alert(JSON.stringify(results[0].geometry,convertLatLngValue,4));
```

where

```
function convertLatLngValue(key,value)
{
    if (key=="lat" || key=="lng") {
        return value();
    }    
    else 
        return value;
}
```

**Live example**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var json = JSON.stringify(results[0].geometry,convertLatLngValue,4);
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = json;
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}


function convertLatLngValue(key,value)
{
    if (key=="lat" || key=="lng") {
        return value();
    }    
    else 
        return value;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
   height: 240px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

#panel {
   position: absolute;
   top: 5px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -180px;
   z-index: 5;
   background-color: #fff;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
 <div id="panel">
        <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
        <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
 </div>
 <div id="map-canvas"></div>
 <pre id="output"></pre>
```